# How To Make Data from RTK as useEffect Params?

Tags: react-redux, rtk-query

I got three components, Search Component, Components A and Components B, a lazyload RTK call useLazyGetItemsQuery();

What I want to achieve is:

1. Search Component input search text;
2. After we got search text, Component A use lazyload call to get Items based on the search text
3. After we got items, component B doing other logic

In component A what I need to do is:

```
const [trigger, {data}:items] = useLazyGetItemsQuery();
if(searchText){
   trigger(searchText.content);
}
```

In the component B, my logic is based on component A's API call result, so it should looks like this:

```
//Get the items from RTK store once items exist, shouldn't call in the initial render
const items = ?
//
useEffect(()=>{
 doSomeLogic
},[items]
)
```

My problem is how should I write component B?

The component B should do nothing in the initial render, it should only work once component A finished the API call and got the data.

If without RTK, I can use selector in component B, but now, can I still write a selector to directly get data from API Slice?
Or should I make another RTK call with params in component B? If I should make another RTK call(I know it's cached), how to prevent the call race with component A?

Comment: I believe you'd want to [select](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/endpoints#select) the cached result you want by cache key, e.g. the `searchText.content` arg used. If you need more help/direction from here can you [edit] the post to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant RTKQ and component code used here?

Comment: Thank you Drew, I think I probably can use trigger() as Rafeal mentioned, thanks for you time!

Answer (score 0):

You can use useQuery hook in your component B to directly access the cached data.
Just remember to set it initially disabled to avoid initial fetch.
Would be something like that:

```
 const { data: items } = useQuery('getItems', () => useLazyGetItemsQuery().trigger(), {
    enabled: false,
    });
    
    useEffect(() => {
  if (items) {
    doSomeLogic(items);
  }
}, [items]);
```

Comment: Thanks, trigger() is good for this, thanks a lot!

Comment: What is `useQuery`? TanStack? Are you seriously suggesting OP use both Redux-Toolkit Query and Tanstack Query? I think this also breaks React's [Rules of Hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) since it's conditionally calling a React hook in a callback function.

Comment: hi @DrewReese, yeah I did try conditional fetching by using trigger(), but still cannot achieve it. I think yours directly select by cache key should solve it, I'll try your way now

Answer (score 0):

There are more than just the basic query/mutation and lazyQuery hooks. See the [Feature Comparison](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#feature-comparison) for details.

Use the [useQueryState](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#usequerystate) hook to simply read a cached result without triggering an endpoint.

[image]

> **Description**
>
> A React hook that reads the request status and cached data from the
> Redux store. The component will re-render as the loading status
> changes and the data becomes available.
>
> Note that this hook does not trigger fetching new data. For that
> use-case, see useQuery or useQuerySubscription.
>
> **Features**
>
> - Returns the latest request status and cached data from the Redux store
> - Re-renders as the request status changes and data becomes available

Export the generated `useGetItemsQueryState` hook and in component B call it with the same search argument used by the trigger function in component A.

Example:

```js
const {
  data: items, // The latest returned result regardless of hook arg, if present
  isSuccess,   // Query has data from a successful load.
} = useGetItemsQueryState(searchText.content);

useEffect(() => {
  if (isSuccess) {
    // doSomeLogic
  }
}, [items, isSuccess]);
```

### Alternative

An alternative would be to select the cached result from state via the API slice's endpoints.

See [endpoints::select](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/endpoints#select)

Example:

```js
const selectItems = React.useMemo(
  () => api.endpoints.getItems.select(searchText.content),
  [searchText.content],
);

const { data: items, isSuccess } = useSelector(selectItems);

useEffect(() => {
  if (isSuccess) {
    // doSomeLogic
  }
}, [items, isSuccess]);
```